# What is the 512 Player Icon referencing?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, there is the following player icon:

[image]

What is the meaning behind this icon? What is it's place in the Overwatch universe? I can't for the life of me figure out what/who it's for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a reference to Zarya's weight lifting record. This can be seen by her tattoo on her shoulder, and two of her sprays have 512 kgs set of weights.

> The 512 tattoo on her shoulder is apparently her weightlifting record; two of her sprays depict a 512kg set of weights. -[source](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zarya)

[image][image]

Comment: You mean 512 kg right? Because in your answer you mention 232 kg but the images show 512 kg

Comment: @slebetman yea, I'm just use to pounds. I forget to use kgs sometimes.

Comment: if the little weight are 512 kg each her record should be greater than that :p

Comment: On a side note, what do you think happens to the tattoo if she ever breaks her own record...

Comment: @JamesTrotter She burns it off with her laser cannon (because russians) and gets it re-inked

Comment: As a physicist I shudder when people add a plural 's' to a unit symbol. That'd mean kilogram*second, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Sweet, thanks Dragonrage and @Pyritie for the answer!

Comment: 512 kg is 1128.77 lbs. I don't know which event it is, but 512 kg would easily break any of the men's records and would shatter the women's. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_weightlifting#Women.27s_records